# twilio stop receiving messages

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are using twilio service to send messages to our customers. We want to provide STOP receiving messages option to our customers.

So when a customer replies STOP, he/she should stop receiving messages. I think twilio has a blacklist to stop sending messages to a customer if the customers chooses to.

However, as an organization, we also want to know if a customer opted out of receiving messages.

How will twilio tell us that a customer opted out of receiving messages? How can we add a web hook such as a rest endpoint in twilio? Is this usecase possible in twilio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

This article explains our default keyword handling: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-

tl;dr If someone texts STOP to your Twilio number we add them to our blacklist then pass the message on to you via the normal webhook process.

Hope that helps.